# Loading dots effect with printf in C

Tags: c, printf

I want to print a simple loading message as "Loading..." where the dots are introduced one by one with delay between them. When the third dot is displayed, I want to erase the dots and start again.

The code I was trying is:

```
PRINTF("Loading");
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
    DelayMs(800);
    PRINTF(".");
}
DelayMs(800);
PRINTF("\r               ");
PRINTF("\r");
```

For some reason I am getting a weird behaviour and I do not know why. What I see on screen is either one of these lines:

```
          .Loading....
Loading   .Loading....
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using arduino? Are you sure your terminal supports `\r` character? How are you displaying the characters?

Comment: We cannot know how your non-standard `PRINTF` function works. Please specify the system you are using. Also, please read about [mcve].

Comment: Please always show real code with real problems and real output. Your code does not print `Listening` but it prints `Loading`. Please don't make up some code that does not match with the output. Use copy&paste to show the real code. Everything else is prone to introducing errors that are not there in your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fflush(stdout)` to force printing when the output does not contain a newline.
The format specifier `%.*s` will output a string of length limited by an integer argument. As `each` in incremented, the number of dots printed will vary from zero to three. The spaces will 'erase' previous dots and the backspace `\b` will erase the spaces.
Being on Linux, I used `sleep` instead of `DelayMS`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( void) {
    for ( int loop = 0; loop < 4; ++loop) {
        for ( int each = 0; each < 4; ++each) {
            printf ( "\rloading%.*s   \b\b\b", each, "...");
            fflush ( stdout);//force printing as no newline in output
            sleep ( 1);
        }
    }
    printf ( "\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to reset the line, try this `printf("\rListening")`
instead of

```
PRINTF("\r>>             ");
PRINTF("\r");
```

It should be:

```
while(condition to stop this animation){
printf("Listening");
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        delay(500);
        printf(".");
    }
 printf("\r");
}
```